# How to find an element's text in Capybara while ignoring inner element text

Tags: ruby, selenium, xpath, capybara, nokogiri

In the HTML example below I am trying to grab the $16.95 text in the outer `span.price` element and exclude the text from the inner `span.sale` one.

```
<div class="price">
  <span class="sale">
    <span class="sale-text">"Low price!"</span>
    "$16.95"
  </span>
</div>
```

If I was using Nokogiri this wouldn't be too difficult.

```
price = doc.css('sale')
price.search('.sale-text').remove
price.text
```

However Capybara navigates rather than removes nodes. I knew something like `price.text` would grab text from all sub elements, so I tried to use xpath to be more specific. `p.find(:xpath, "//span[@class='sale']", :match => :first).text`. However this grabs text from the inner element as well.

Finally, I tried looping through all spans to see if I could separate the results but I get an Ambiguous error.

```
p.find(:css, 'span').each { |result| puts result.text }
Capybara::Ambiguous: Ambiguous match, found 2 elements matching css "span"
```

I am using Capybara/Selenium as this is for a web scraping project with authentication complications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no single statement way to do this with Capybara since the DOMs concept of innerText doesn't really support what you want to do. Assuming `p` is the '.price' element, two ways you could get what you want are as follows:

1. Since you know the node you want to ignore just subtract that text from the whole text

   ```
   p.find('span.sale').text.sub(p.find('span.sale-text').text, '')
   ```
2. Grab the innerHTML string and parse that with Nokogiri or Capybara.string (which just wraps Nokogiri elements in the Capybara DSL)

   ```
   doc = Capybara.string(p['innerHTML'])
   nokogiri_fragment = doc.native
   #do whatever you want with the nokogiri fragment
   ```

Comment: Appreciate the answer, but I ended up just scraping the html with Capybara and processing with Nokogiri. I needed to navigate through many results pages, and the combination of parsing with slow Capybara nodes and strange JS effects made the script usually throw a StaleElementReferenceError.